# How to get decimal result when converting nanosecond to millisecond?

Tags: java, timeunit

Using `TimeUnit`, how can I convert 665477 nanosecond to 0.665477 millisecond?

```
long t = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(665477L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

This always gives `0` but I need decimal points precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Java Documentation - [TimeUnit#convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
public long convert(long sourceDuration,TimeUnit sourceUnit)
```

> Convert the given time duration in the given unit to this unit.
>   Conversions from finer to coarser granularities truncate, so lose
>   precision. For example converting 999 milliseconds to seconds results
>   in 0. Conversions from coarser to finer granularities with arguments
>   that would numerically overflow saturate to Long.MIN_VALUE if negative
>   or Long.MAX_VALUE if positive.

So to get your answer

```
double milliseconds = 665477 / 1000000.0;
```

Comment: That's a real shame because one of the principal reasons to use a convert method is because writing out all those 0's is so error prone.

Answer (score 6):

shorter and less error prone:

```
double millis = 665477 / 1E6;
```

milli -> mikro -> nano

are two steps, each step has a conversion faktor of 1000 = 1E3;
So makes one million, which can easier be read as 1E6, than by counting zeros.

Answer (score 4):

Just divide by 1,000,000:

```
double millis = 665477 / 1000000.0;
```

With `TimeUnit` you will only get an integer result.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate this manualy

```
double mil = 665477L/1_000_000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double milliSeconds = nanoSeconds / (double) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1);
```

so you don't have to put the magic number 1_000_000.0 in your code, or remember what is the correct ratio to make sure there is no bug: the line is pretty self-validating.

You can `import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;` for a code reading even more like prose.